# All Iframe content and CDN not working anymore

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, iframe, cdn

My Node App seems to be blocking all CDN and iframe content, for an example, my tables are not loading the dataTables stuff (like sorting and searching), my graphs are not working either. They were all working before, last thing I modified was package updates and node update that doesn't seem to be connected to the problem. I would like to know what is possibly happening and how to solve it.

I'm sorry if the question is not so objective but I really have no ideia where to start here.

Comment: You could start with a proper problem description, at least. _“My Node App seems to be blocking all CDN and iframe content”_ - and that means what, _exactly_?

Comment: Right, I edited the question with 2 examples.

Comment: That is still saying little more than “not working”. Do you get any JavaScript errors in the browser console? What about the network requests that are happening, do those get answered as expected, or are there HTTP error codes showing somewhere?

Comment: Graphs just do not appear, cnd masks are not applied, iframe content gives a grayscreen saying the content is blocked.

Comment: Blocked by who/what? Full, specific error message (quote)?

Comment: Translating from my language is something like "This content is blocked. contact the site owner to fix the issue"

Comment: I found out now that it's probably related to content security policy.

Comment: Either that, or X-Frame-Options (in case of iframes.) Either way, _both_ should leave messages telling you what happened and why, in the browser console.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230233/discussion-between-eduardo-conte-and-cbroe).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### The Problem

To document and help other people who may experience this same problem. Based on CBroe's comments I figured out that the problem was that I had not set a **Content Security Policy** (CSP), and the browser set its own policy, which blocked external resources (CDNs and Iframe contents). The error message mentioning Content Security Policy was being displayed in the browser console.

### The solution

To solve the problem I add a middleware on **server.js** to set a CSP that would not block my external content.

Example of a very permissive CSP middleware (I recommend you to use a more restrictive one):

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.setHeader(
    "Content-Security-Policy",
    "default-src * 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; script-src * 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; connect-src * 'unsafe-inline'; img-src * data: blob: 'unsafe-inline'; frame-src *; style-src * 'unsafe-inline';"
  );
  return next();
});
```